# IOS. Streaming internet radio

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, audio-streaming

I need to play an internet radio in different formats. I tried to play radio use MPMoviePlayerController, but it stopping after 3-4 seconds.

```
var urlAddress = "http://streaming.radionomy.com/Elium-ClubDance";
var url = NSURL( string:urlAddress);
var player = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;
player.prepareToPlay();
player.play();
```

Does somebody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

From your question I create a new project and try this code :

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://streaming.radionomy.com/Elium-ClubDance")!

    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

    moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()

    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming

    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

    moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer.play()

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

    }
}
```

Working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I think the problem is with Radionomy.  This used to work and your code works if you change the URL to another one that does not point to Radionomy.